# workaround for ggplot2::facet_grid 'big' data bug?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid, ggpubr

More like "medium data", because a mere 16k rows is enough to reproduce this.

##### Working:

```
library(ggplot2)
outputdir = "/tmp"
mtdf = NULL
for(i in 1:100){
  mti = mtcars[,c("disp","hp","wt","gear","carb","mpg","qsec","vs","am")]
  mti$disp = mti$disp + 10*rnorm(length(mti$disp))
  mti$hp = mti$hp + 10*rnorm(length(mti$hp))
  mti$wt = mti$wt + 10*rnorm(length(mti$wt))
  mtdf = rbind(mtdf,mti)
}
p = ggplot(mtdf,aes(disp,hp,color=wt)) + 
      geom_point()+
      facet_nested(gear ~ am,scales="free")
ggsave(plot=p,file=file.path(outputdir,"facet_scatter.pdf"),width=10,height=10)
```

[image]

##### Not Working (various alternative approaches):

Here is the output of `sessionInfo()` showing the package versions that are loaded.  This MWE was run on linux.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(ggh4x)

outputdir = "/tmp"

mtdf = NULL
for(i in 1:500){
  mti = mtcars[,c("disp","hp","wt","gear","carb","mpg","qsec","vs","am")]
  mti$disp = mti$disp + 10*rnorm(length(mti$disp))
  mti$hp = mti$hp + 10*rnorm(length(mti$hp))
  mti$wt = mti$wt + 10*rnorm(length(mti$wt))
  mtdf = rbind(mtdf,mti)
}
p = ggplot(mtdf,aes(disp,hp,color=wt)) + 
      geom_point()+
      facet_nested(gear ~ am,scales="free")
ggsave(plot=p,file=file.path(outputdir,"facet_scatter.png"),width=10,height=10)

p = ggplot(mtdf,aes(disp,hp,color=wt)) + 
      geom_point()+
      facet_grid(gear ~ am,scales="free")
ggsave(plot=p,file=file.path(outputdir,"facet_scatter.png"),width=10,height=10)

p = ggscatter(mtdf,x="disp",y="hp",color="wt")
p = facet(p,facet.by=c("gear","am"))
ggsave(plot=p,file=file.path(outputdir,"facet_scatter.png"),width=10,height=10)
```

##### All three attempts generate the following error:

```
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10) -- "Kick Things"
Copyright (C) 2021 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under certain conditions.
Type 'license()' or 'licence()' for distribution details.

  Natural language support but running in an English locale

R is a collaborative project with many contributors.
Type 'contributors()' for more information and
'citation()' on how to cite R or R packages in publications.

Type 'demo()' for some demos, 'help()' for on-line help, or
'help.start()' for an HTML browser interface to help.
Type 'q()' to quit R.

source("/mnt/md0/insshare/mkarikom/Active_Project_Backup/DURIAN/DURIAN/slurm/test.R", encoding = "UTF-8")
Error: `scale_id` must not be `NA`
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_rt.so

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggh4x_0.2.1   ggpubr_0.4.0  ggplot2_3.3.5

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] pillar_1.6.4     compiler_4.1.1   tools_4.1.1      jsonlite_1.7.2  
 [5] lifecycle_1.0.1  tibble_3.1.6     gtable_0.3.0     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
 [9] rlang_0.4.12     DBI_1.1.2        withr_2.4.3      dplyr_1.0.7     
[13] generics_0.1.1   vctrs_0.3.8      grid_4.1.1       tidyselect_1.1.1
[17] glue_1.6.0       R6_2.5.1         rstatix_0.7.0    fansi_1.0.0     
[21] carData_3.0-5    purrr_0.3.4      tidyr_1.1.4      farver_2.1.0    
[25] car_3.0-12       magrittr_2.0.1   scales_1.1.1     backports_1.4.1 
[29] ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1 abind_1.4-5      colorspace_2.0-2
[33] ggsignif_0.6.3   utf8_1.2.2       munsell_0.5.0    broom_0.7.11    
[37] crayon_1.4.2
```

##### `rang::last_error()`

As suggested in the error message:

```
> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
`scale_id` must not be `NA`
Backtrace:
  1. ggplot2::ggsave(...)
  3. ggplot2:::grid.draw.ggplot(plot)
  5. ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  7. ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  8. layout$train_position(data, scale_x(), scale_y())
  9. ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 10. self$facet$train_scales(...)
 11. ggplot2:::f(...)
 12. ggplot2:::scale_apply(layer_data, x_vars, "train", SCALE_X, x_scales)
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
```

##### `rang::last_trace()`

As suggested in the output of `slang::last_error()`

```
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
`scale_id` must not be `NA`
Backtrace:
     █
  1. └─ggplot2::ggsave(...)
  2.   ├─grid::grid.draw(plot)
  3.   └─ggplot2:::grid.draw.ggplot(plot)
  4.     ├─base::print(x)
  5.     └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  6.       ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  7.       └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  8.         └─layout$train_position(data, scale_x(), scale_y())
  9.           └─ggplot2:::f(..., self = self)
 10.             └─self$facet$train_scales(...)
 11.               └─ggplot2:::f(...)
 12.                 └─ggplot2:::scale_apply(layer_data, x_vars, "train", SCALE_X, x_scales)
```

#### Update:

It's possible that this is due to the scales 1.1.1 package

Comment: All of these examples seem to work without a problem on R 4.1.1 (macOS), with ggplot2 3.3.5, ggh4x 0.2.1 (required for your first example but not shown in your code), and ggpubr 0.4.0. Are you sure you don't have some object or function hanging around in your environment that is getting referred to in error? What happens if you try to produce a fully reproducible case with the code above using e.g. reprex?

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I've updated the MWE and re-run it in a new r session with the three libraries explicitly loaded.  Additionally I've given the full output (from session start) including `sessionInfo()` and the previously reported error

Comment: Works for me on r-devel (PopOS! 21.04) with the same package versions ... (I did have to define "outputdir" first). (What does rlang::last_error() say ... ?)

Comment: thanks for the feedback.  I've updated the post with output of `last_error()` and `last_trace()`.  I guess the biggest puzzle for me is why it works great for all of us with a few hundred rows and stops working on mine with more... This is a workstation with 128gb RAM and a 16 core cpu and the load on these resources is minimal now, so its definitely not hardware.

Comment: honestly, this probably has something to do with random stuff I tried to make JuliaCall [not] work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is related to libmkl.

I can reproduce the failure mentioned above and avoid it by switch from MKL to openblas ( update-alternatives --config libblas.so.3-x86_64-linux-gnu ).

Simple code to reproduce the problem

```
    library(ggplot2)
    sessionInfo()
    f <- function(n) {
        df <- data.frame(v = c("V1","V2", "V1", "V2"),
                 l = seq(1, 4*n), t = seq(4*n, 1), 
                 p = c("P_1", "P2", "P3", "P_1"))

        ggplot(data = df, aes(l, t)) + 
            geom_point() + 
            facet_grid(rows = vars(p), cols = vars(v))
    }

    f(100)
    f(10000)
```

Runs well with openblas and fails, when using MKL.

```
> library(ggplot2)
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.3.1 (2023-06-16)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)

Matrix products: default
BLAS/LAPACK: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libmkl_rt.so;  LAPACK version 3.8.0

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

time zone: Europe/Berlin
tzcode source: system (glibc)

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] ggplot2_3.4.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] utf8_1.2.3       R6_2.5.1         tidyselect_1.2.0 magrittr_2.0.3  
 [5] gtable_0.3.4     glue_1.6.2       tibble_3.2.1     pkgconfig_2.0.3 
 [9] generics_0.1.3   dplyr_1.1.3      lifecycle_1.0.3  cli_3.6.1       
[13] fansi_1.0.4      scales_1.2.1     grid_4.3.1       vctrs_0.6.3     
[17] withr_2.5.0      compiler_4.3.1   munsell_0.5.0    pillar_1.9.0    
[21] colorspace_2.1-0 rlang_1.1.1     
> 
> f <- function(n) 
+ {
+   df <- data.frame(v = c("V1","V2", "V1", "V2"),
+                  l = seq(1, 4*n),
+                  t = seq(4*n, 1), 
+                  p = c("P_1", "P2", "P3", "P_1"))
+   ggplot(data = df, aes(l, t)) + 
+     geom_point() + 
+     facet_grid(rows = vars(p), cols = vars(v))
+ }
> 
> f(100)
> f(10000)
Error in `scale_apply()`:
! `scale_id` must not contain any "NA"
Backtrace:
     ▆
  1. ├─base (local) `<fn>`(x)
  2. └─ggplot2:::print.ggplot(x)
  3.   ├─ggplot2::ggplot_build(x)
  4.   └─ggplot2:::ggplot_build.ggplot(x)
  5.     └─layout$train_position(data, scale_x(), scale_y())
  6.       └─ggplot2 (local) train_position(..., self = self)
  7.         └─self$facet$train_scales(...)
  8.           └─ggplot2 (local) train_scales(...)
  9.             └─ggplot2:::scale_apply(layer_data, x_vars, "train", SCALE_X, x_scales)
 10.               └─cli::cli_abort("{.arg scale_id} must not contain any {.val NA}")
 11.                 └─rlang::abort(...)
Execution halted
```